# Data Generation with Variational Autoencoders

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

For creating combinations of different parameters in a given range I stumbled over Variational Autoencoders. I followed the tutorials of [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae#display_a_generated_image_from_the_last_training_epoch) and [Keras](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/#build-the-encoder) and adapted it to work with numerical data.

For testing i generated a training dataset that is completely even.

```
def getTrainData():
        column_ranges = {
            '1': np.arange(0, 4, 1),
            '2': np.arange(0, 4, 1),
            '3': np.arange(0, 4, 1),
            '4': np.arange(0, 4, 1),
            '5': np.arange(0, 4, 1),
            '6': np.arange(0, 4, 1)
        }

        # Generate all possible combinations of the ranges
        combinations = DataFrame(list(product(*column_ranges.values())))
        return combinations
```

When using this data for training and trying to have a `latent dimension` of **2** the not only the reconstruction is of the data is really bad also some variance seem to be lost. The follow images show that for really bad results datapoints above 2 seem to get lost. Also values below 1.2 seem to vanish. and even for better results - they are far away from a good reconstruction.

[image]
[image]

Since reconstruction is not that important for me since i aim to generate all possible combinations within the test space it would be fine if i could generate them from sampling the latent space and using the decoder to reconstruct them.

But even when trying to reconstruct them from the latent space a lot of combinations don't seem to be generated.

[image]

Is the VAE not suitable for this task since there is no correlation within the data? In my general thoughts it should be possible to map these 6 features to a 2 dimensional space even if there is no correlation.

Since it could also be possible that it is a bug in my coding below you can find a minimal reproducable sample.

```
class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.mean_squared_error(data, reconstruction)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }

def create_vae(shape):
    class Sampling(Layer):
        def call(self, inputs):
            z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
            batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
            dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
            epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
            return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

def create_encoder(input_shape):
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(input_shape,))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=VAE_ACTIVATION_FUN)(encoder_inputs)
    z_mean = keras.layers.Dense(LATENT_DIM, name="z_mean")(x)
    z_log_var = keras.layers.Dense(LATENT_DIM, activation=VAE_ACTIVATION_FUN,  name="z_log_var")(x)
    z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
    encoder = Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
    return encoder

def create_decoder(output_shape):
    latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(LATENT_DIM, ))
    x = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=VAE_ACTIVATION_FUN)(latent_inputs)
    decoder_outputs = Dense(output_shape, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    decoder = Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
    return decoder

###run the code
vae = VAE(create_encoder(shape), create_decoder(shape))
return vae

train = getTrainData()

input_scaler = MinMaxScaler()

if (NORMALIZE):
    input_scaler.fit(train)
    train = input_scaler.transform(train)

vae = create_vae(len(DataFrame(train).columns))
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(train, shuffle=True, epochs=300, batch_size=500)

test = getTestData() ## generates random samples in the same paramater space as test data e.g. [0.0, 0.5, 1, 3, 1, 2.5]

if (NORMALIZE):
    test = input_scaler.transform(test)

# combinations_array = np.array(combinations)
_, _, encoded = vae.encoder.predict(test)
predictions = vae.decoder.predict(encoded)

if (NORMALIZE):
    test = input_scaler.inverse_transform(test)
    predictions = input_scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

if (PLOT_VAE_PREDICTIONS):
    # Plot for each column in the target variable
    for i, column in enumerate(DataFrame(test).columns):
        plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(test[:, i], predictions[:, i])
        plt.xlabel('Expected')
        plt.ylabel('Prediction')
        # plt.title('Predicted vs. Expected - ' + column)
        plt.show()
```